# Custom table for own commands

Tags: table-of-contents

I have created following four command and using them just below \section

```
\coursename{Mathematics for Biotechnology/Food Technology-I}
\credit{4}
\lecture{3}
\tutorial{1}
\lab{0}
```

I want to generate automatic table like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
S. No.     Subject Name                                    L    T    P    Credit
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1.    Mathematics for Biotechnology/Food Technology-I      3    1    0      4
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2. ....
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This table will appear just below chapter like environment.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: This looks an assignment sheet, perhaps `exsheets` is the correct package for this?

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What should be in the second line? At second glance it does not look like an assignment, is rather an overview table of courses and possible credits.

Comment: If I use similar commands with other inputs, those should be appended to table. It seems similar to table of content (But it is not). exsheet has no such option.

Comment: Something like a `minitoc` with a custom format, if it is to appear below a chapter like environment

Comment: I will think about it...

Comment: I tried minitoc too. Here I have 6 columns (like table). It may possible if minitoc may be customized like this. But I am unable to do that. Sample output : [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0V3o5HnwE4tWTFucWFqd1RYLWs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are two issues: One is the entry to something like a `list of courses` and the other is the `listofcourses` command (let's called it that way) I am not sure, how you call your commands above. Please post a small document in which you show what you tried so so far.

Comment: What does `P` stand for, in the heading of the table?

Comment: I have loaded zipped folder on google drive: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0V3o5HnwE4tRlBLTU1jUDdxckU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: P for lab (Practical)

Comment: Do you stick to `\subsection{\courseinfo}` commands?

Comment: nop, we may think some other alternative. That is helpfull if we generate table of content.

Comment: Few people will download a zip file merely to answer a question. Please read the link @ChristianHupfer provided and **post a minimum working example *in your question***. Note that your question should be such that it can ***benefit other users*** of the site - not just you. That means it should be self-contained and not depend on files you post elsewhere. (Or can you guarantee those links will remain active for as long as TeX SE does?)

Comment: @DrAmitKAwasthi: I added a possible solution, but I am unsatisfied with that `bibliography`, because it appears on a separate page. I could redefine this, but I omitted it for the moment.

Comment: @DrAmitKAwasthi: Could you give some feedback about the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is something like this, where I added key-values to use the additional information about courses, the order of the key-values does not matter.

```
\CourseInfo[]{Course Description}{bib entries}
```

It will use a `\subsection{Course Number Subject Name}` and print the description and adds a small bibliography.

Currently you must specifiy the course keys, I will update to a more failsafe version.

If you add new `\CourseInfo`, remove `\jobname.crs` in the local directory. I have no check for overwritting so far.

The `\listofcourses` will print an overview.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{xkeyval}%

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{course}%
\newwrite\courselistfile%


\newcommand{\addcourselist}[6]{%
\immediate\write\courselistfile{%
  \number\value{course} \string& #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 & #5 & #6\tabularnewline
  \string\hline%
}%
}%

\newcommand{\listofcourses}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c |c |p{2.7in} |c|c|c|c|}
\hline%
  \textbf{S.No.} & \textbf{Subject Code} & \textbf{Subject} & \textbf{L} & \textbf{T} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{Credit}  \tabularnewline
  \hline%
  \hline%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.crs}{\input{\jobname.crs}}{\input{\jobname.crs}}%
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\clearpage
}%

\makeatletter
\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{CourseCode}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysSubjectCode{#1}%
}

\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{Subject}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysSubject{#1}%
}

\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{Lectures}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysLectures{#1}%
}

\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{Tutorial}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysTutorial{#1}%
}

\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{Practical}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysPractical{#1}%
}

\define@key{CourseInfoKeys}{Credit}[]{%
\def\CourseInfoKeysCredit{#1}%
}%
\makeatother



\newcommand{\CourseInfo}[3][]{%
\setkeys{CourseInfoKeys}{#1}%
%
\refstepcounter{course}%
\addcourselist{\CourseInfoKeysSubjectCode}{\CourseInfoKeysSubject}{\CourseInfoKeysLectures}{\CourseInfoKeysTutorial}{
\CourseInfoKeysPractical}{\CourseInfoKeysCredit}%
\subsection{\CourseInfoKeysSubjectCode~\CourseInfoKeysSubject}%
#2% Course Description
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\ifblank{#3}{%
}{%
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
#3
\end{thebibliography}%
}%
\clearpage
}%


\AtBeginDocument{%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.crs}{%
}{%
\immediate\openout\courselistfile=\jobname.crs
}
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\courselistfile%
}%


\begin{document}
\listofcourses

\CourseInfo[CourseCode={AS 601},Subject={Research Methodology},Lectures={3}, Tutorial={0}, Practical={0},Credit={3}]{%
Objectives and types of research: Motivation and objectives – Research methods vs Methodology. Types of research – Descriptive vs. Analytical, Applied vs. Fundamental, Quantitative vs. Qualitative, Conceptual vs. Empirical. 
}{%
\bibitem{p} Design and Analysis of Experiments by Montogomery D.C. (2001), John Wiley, ISBN: 0471260088  
\bibitem{p} Satarkar, S.V., 2000. Intellectual property rights and Copy right. Ess Ess Publications. 
}%

\CourseInfo[CourseCode={MA 604},Subject={Linear Algebra and ODE},Lectures={2}, Tutorial={0}, Practical={0},Credit={2}]{%
\textsc{Review of Linear Algebra:} Finite dimensional Vector spaces; basis and dimension; Linear transformations and their matrix representation; eigen values and eigen vectors; digonalization; invariant spaces and Canonical forms.
}{%
\bibitem{p} Kenneth Hoffman, R Kunze, \emph{Linear Algebra}, 2th edition, PHI, 1971
\bibitem{p} Gilbert Strang, \emph{Linear Algebra and Its Applications}, 4th edition, Brooks/Cole (Cengage Learning), 2006
\bibitem{p} Gilbert Strang, \emph{Introduction to Linear Algebra}, 4th edition, Cambridge University Press India Pvt Ltd, 2009
\bibitem{p} \url{http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/}
}%
\end{document}
```

**Note** The table is not a table of contents in its original sense. It should be replaced by a `\longtable` environment

[image]